# Quemar etiqueta [fecha]

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

El tipo de datos `Date` se implementa de diferentes formas en diferentes lenguajes:

- En Visual Studio 2015: es un número de punto flotante que representa los [días transcurridos desde el 30/dic/1899](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69.aspx)
- En Python es un [objeto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- En [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) el número de milisegundos desde el EPOC.

Por poner solo un ejemplo.

Dado que el tipo de datos `Date`, `datetime` o `date` significa diferentes cosas para diferentes lenguajes, **¿es prudente quemar la etiqueta?**. Hay 46 preguntas con la etiqueta [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha), en diferentes lenguajes: javascript, vba, python, mysql, sql, html, etc...

Siendo congruentes, no existe la etiqueta `entero`, `float` o `integer`, pero si `string` (con 125 preguntas) y `double`, aunque esta última no tiene preguntas.

Comment: Hasta donde vi que se use, [TAG:fecha] no es para un tipo de datos, sino para preguntas referidas a temas de fechas​... Me resulta un poco difícil entender el motivo para quemarla. Creo que sería bueno si pudieses dar más detalles de por qué crees que habría que quemarla. Y quizás convenga reetiquetar de [meta-tag:soporte] a [meta-tag:discusión]

Comment: Me parece que [tag:fecha] debería referirse al concepto general y no a un tipo de datos. Aunque no tiene que ser igual allá que aquí, así pasa en [so] donde [date](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/date) tiene 44,100 preguntas. Creo que la discusión debería ser acerca de la orientación de uso de la etiqueta en cuestión.

Comment: @toledano quizás te interese [¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3210/127)

Answer (score 4):

El manejo de fechas, como concepto, siempre ha sido problemático: todo el mundo entiende el concepto intuitivo de lo que es una fecha pero en cuanto profundizamos vemos que la implementación de una API para manejar fechas, fechas con horas, calendarios gregorianos, Julianos, judío, musulmán, chino... además de los segundos intercalares, horarios de verano o invierno y husos horarios tiene una complejidad excepcional. 
Date, Time, Instant o Datetime son nombres de tipos o clases usados a menudos en los diferentes lenguajes y librerías, pero [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha) permite englobar el concepto, lo que puede ayudar a hacer preguntas más teóricas o "language agnostic".
Por tanto creo que deberíamos mantener el tag, que puede ser siempre acompañado del tag correspondiente lenguage de programación que requiera la pregunta o, incluso, del API que estemos usando (Java por ejemplo tiene java.util.Date, JodaTime, java.time.* ...)