# Llegó el día de ponernos de acuerdo sobre qué hacer con fecha, date y datetime

Tags: discusión, desambiguación-etiquetas

Tenemos al menos tres etiquetas sobre fechas que no tienen una orientación de uso del todo clara

- [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha)
- [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date)
- [datetime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime)

En particular las primeras dos, [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha) y [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) me parecen ambiguas pues podrían significar diferentes cosas para diferentes personas. Por ejemplo,

- podrían ser sinónimos una de la otra pues podrían asumirse que se refiere al concepto [fecha](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fecha), siendo una la traducción directa de la otra
- podrían referirse al tipo de dato fecha, lo cual asumo que en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación se llama Date.
- En algunos lenguajes el tipo de dato fecha (date) sólo incluye día, mes y año pero en otros como JavaScript también incluye hora, minuto, segundo y zona horaria, para los cual otros lenguajes usan [datetime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime).

Propongo que la orientación de uso de

- [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha) se enfoque en el concepto general
- [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) se enfoque en el tipo de dato que sólo incluyen día, mes y año
- [datetime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) se enfoque en el tipo de dato que incluye día, mes, año, hora, minuto, segundo y zona horaria.

¿Cómo ven?

Relacionado

- [Quemar etiqueta [fecha]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1877/65)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con dejar las etiquetas dependiendo de la tecnología en cuestión? Sin mas detalles pareciera que no se resolvería la ambigüedad.

Comment: Ayudaría que hicieras una propuesta sobre orientación de uso de `date` ¿te animas?

Answer (score 7):

Primeramente, considero que antes de formar un criterio o regla a la hora de hacer uso de esas etiquetas, debemos tomar en cuenta la cantidad de lenguajes que hacen referencia a las palabras reservadas/funciones/métodos `Date` y/o `DateTime`.

Tomar como regla que la etiqueta [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) se enfoque en el tipo de dato que sólo incluyen día, mes y año, pierde sentido en ciertas tecnologías. Por ejemplo, una pregunta de C# que hace referencia a hacer uso de una fecha corta  (día, mes y año) no puede ser etiquetada como [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) porque no existe nada que haga referencia en ese lenguaje y todo el manejo de fechas se realiza a través de la clase `DateTime`, ya sea para una fecha corta (día, mes y año) o para una fecha larga (día, mes, año, hora, minuto, segundo, milisegundo). Caso similar ocurre con Javascript donde el uso de fechas se realiza directamente a través de la función `Date`. En el caso de C# sería adecuado etiquetar con [datetime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) y en el caso de Javascript con [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) sin importar el formato.

No obstante, otros lenguajes tienen el manejo de fechas segmentado, como el caso de SQL, tienen el tipo de dato `DATE` para el manejo de fechas cortas y `DATETIME` para fechas largas. En este caso sí se debe especificar con cuál de los dos tipos de dato se tiene el problema.

En resumen, intentar segmentar el uso de [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) y [datetime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) no depende directamente del formato de la fecha, sino del lenguaje/tecnología en cuestión. Además de que puede distorsionar el mensaje del usuario que pregunta haciendo referencia a algo que no existe en ese lenguaje/tecnología (justo lo que explicaba en el segundo párrafo).

**Propuesta y orientación de uso**

- [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha) se enfoque en el concepto general
- [date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) el uso está limitado a la tecnología en cuestión, Sinónimo de [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha).
- [datetime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) el uso está limitado a la tecnología en cuestión. Sinónimo de [fecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fecha).